Flutter Shared Preferences It doesn't compile for me
**Please I need help in Flutter because every time I import the shared preferences library I get this error: **
What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences_android:extractDebugAnnotations'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences_android:detachedConfiguration1'.
Could not find intellij-core-31.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:31.1.0).
Searched in the following locations: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/31.1.0/intellij-core-31.1.0. jar > Could not find kotlin-compiler-31.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:31.1.0).
Searched in the following locations: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/31.1.0/kotlin-compiler-31.1.0. jar

This didn't happen to me, but when I updated Flutter it started with this little problem

To fix this issue with the shared_preferences library after updating Flutter:

Update the shared_preferences version in your pubspec.yaml file to the latest.
Run flutter pub get to update dependencies.
Clear the project cache with flutter clean and flutter pub get.
Ensure the Android Gradle Plugin is up to date by checking your android/build.gradle file for the latest plugin version.

This should resolve the dependency issues.
